# Table with FK refer to a table with two PK

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have table1 with id and name columns both as PK, table2 would have a FK that refer to table1 column: name, when I make the FK in MySQL workbench, I get this error:

```
ERROR 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

**table1:** level, id enum(), name varchar(20) BOTH PK.

**table2:** class, id bigint PK AutoIncrement, level_name varchar(20), number int.

`level_name` is the FK to the PK name

Comment: Post your table definitions and adding fk query in your question

Comment: Hi, Oracle and MySQL are two separate RDBMS, though Oracle owns MySQL you don't need both tags as you're using MySQL; not Oracle. Equally, you don't seem to be having any Java or JPA issues so there doesn't seem to be a need for these tags.

Comment: Ben, I know I add it + java so many people can see my question, I even work with both of them

Comment: Well that's... nice @user3923327, but you also want people to help you. Deliberately pushing your question in front of the eyes of people who have no desire to see it isn't polite and makes it less likely that people will help. You got your answer in 27 minutes without the extra eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding foreign key you need to care somethings like in your case in table1 that is level you have made `PRIMARY KEY (id,name)` and in second table you are referencing `level_name` to be the foreign key which  is wrong you need to refer the pair of columns from your class table in order to create a foreign key add `level_id` of same type of `id` column from table1 `level` and then reference this pair `FOREIGN KEY (level_id, level_name)` to table `level` see below sample schema for your tables

```
CREATE TABLE `level` (
  `id` enum('1','2','3','4','5') NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `class` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `level_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `level_id` enum('1','2','3','4','5') DEFAULT NULL,
  `number` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_key` (`level_id`,`level_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_key` FOREIGN KEY (`level_id`, `level_name`)
  REFERENCES `level` (`id`, `name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90acc1)